# Finding incomplete geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with the notion of incomplete geodesics. Can someone give me a minimal example for such a geodesic?

In particular, I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Consider the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}:= \{(x,y):y>0\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ equiped with the metric: $g_{q}:=\frac{1}{y^q}\delta_i^j$ for some real number $q>0,q\not=2$ (for $q=2$ you obtain the poincare half-plane model.)
**Show that $(\mathbb{H},g_q)$ is not geodesically complete.**

(Hint: Consider unit-speed geodesics starting at $(x_0,y_0):=(0,1)$)

So far I found the following system of ordinary differential equations:

$x''\cdot y=q\cdot (x'y')$

$y''\cdot y=\frac{q}{2}((y')^2-(x')^2)$

$y^q=(x')^2+(y')^2$

Comment: minimal example $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. I do not believe this is research level mathematics so I've voted to migrate to math.stackexchange.

Comment: On that example you use normal euclidean metric so it's trivial to find geodesic for it because it is just every line passing through origin as example of "bad" geodesic. I don't see any similarity between that example and half plane with given metric from above except they are both geodesically incomplete.

Comment: You asked for a minimal example. This is one

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try integrating up (if $q > 2$) or down (if $q < 2$) the $y$-axis.

Comment: Sorry but eq. that I get like that do not look easy to slove also or I am doing something not good?

Comment: The point is, one segment or the other of the $y$-axis has finite length, so the boundary of the half-plane lies at finite distance. But to see the $y$-axis is a (pre-)geodesic, it suffices to solve your system with $x' = 0$.... :)

Comment: I had a typo in last line so eq. I don´t know how to get parametrization for ex. of that y axis with respect to my metric. In case q=2 I solve my eq. and I get that vertical lines are parametrized with some constant on first place and $e^t$ for y. So how I get that for this case because my ide is to see that I can not put every t inside and that is why is geo.incomplete? Thank you for the answers before.

Comment: If $x' = 0$, your last equation can be rearranged to $y' = \pm y^{q/2}$, which is separable and easily solved...?